# NSFetchedResultsController: using of NSManagedObjectContext during update brings to crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Here is the interface of my controller class:

```
@interface ProjectListViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
}

@end
```

I use following code to init **fetchedResultsController**:

```
if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

    // Create and configure a fetch request with the Project entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Create the sort descriptors array.
    NSSortDescriptor *projectIdDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"projectId" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:projectIdDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Create and initialize the fetch results controller.
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                                            managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
                                                                                              sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                                                                                       cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

As you can see, I am using the same **managedObjectContext** as defined in my controller class

Here is an adoption of the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
        UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

        switch(type) {

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self _configureCell:(TDBadgedCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                if (newIndexPath != nil) {
                    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                }
                else {
                    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                }
            break;
        }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
        switch(type) {

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Inside of the _configureCell:atIndexPath: method I have following code:

```
    NSFetchRequest *issuesNumberRequest = [NSFetchRequest new];
    NSEntityDescription *issueEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Issue" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [issuesNumberRequest setEntity:issueEntity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"projectId == %@", project.projectId];
    [issuesNumberRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSUInteger issuesNumber = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:issuesNumberRequest error:nil];
    [issuesNumberRequest release];
```

I am using the managedObjectContext again.

But when I am trying to insert new Project, app crashes with following exception:

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView
>   _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-984.38/UITableView.m:774
>   Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The
>   number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (4)
>   must be equal to the number of rows
>   contained in that section before the
>   update (4), plus or minus the number
>   of rows inserted or deleted from that
>   section (1 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Fortunately, I've found a workaround: if I create and use separate NSManagedObjectContext inside of the _configureCell:atIndexPath: method app won't crash!

I only want to know, is this behavior correct or not?

[Here is a sample project.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1999451/Bug%238043735.zip)
Pay your attention to '_configureCell:atIndexPath:' and '_addSomeRows' methods of CrashMeViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in iOS 4.0